# How to scrape a span from a div using BS4 and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape those lines of code from a website, my focus is what is between the spans, unluckily i didn't managed to scrape it, i kept getting weird errors.

```html
<div class="u-font-weight-bold u-font-size-l be-lot-current-bid__amount-label"><span class="u-no-wrap u-margin-r-small">Offerta attuale 222 € </span></div>
```

Do you guys knows how to get "Offerta attuale 222 €"?

Comment: Please include your code, details about any errors and ideally a link to the website. Right click inspect element, the target element on your page, and copy the selector/xpath and share that. Something that shows us where value is present in case value changes/the html shared is repeated on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With full html and your script it may be easier to help you.

Try this and tell me if it works fine for you.

```
offerta = soup.find(class_ = 'u-no-wrap u-margin-r-small').get_text()
```